# Why Gaussian method is recommended for $4\times4$ determinant?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I wanted to know why Gaussian elimination method in Linear Algebra has order of $n^3$
for calculation and found [this](http://www.math.ryerson.ca/~danziger/professor/MTH108/Handouts/gauss-complexity.pdf).But I don't know why this:

> From the table of $n^3$ vs $n!$ we see that $4^3 > n!$, yet the Gaussian method is the one that is
>   generally recommended for calculating $4 × 4$ determinants, why?

Also, if you can suggest other link for "why Gaussian elimination method in Linear Algebra has order of $n^3$", I will be obliged.

Comment: Recommended by whom? The only specific observation about 4x4 determinants is to not use the straightforward generalization of Sarrus' rule, because it doesn't give you the $4!$ terms it should. Gauss elimination is preferred to Laplace's theorem for large matrices. Maybe you have heard someone mixing the words of these two observations.

Comment: Thank you. Can you provide other link to clarify my doubt about order of $n^3$?(Also, no one recommended this. I was reading Mathematics for Economists by Simon and Blume and got a sentence mentioning order of $n^3$ without explanation why so. Then I googled for it and got the mentioned link.)

Comment: Dear Sush, This morning I had to compute the determinant of a $4\times 4$ matrix, and I used cofactor expansion, not Gaussian elimination.  Regards,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When evaluating algorithms such as Gaussian elimination and cofactor expansion, the primary operations are **addition** and **multiplication**.  Of these, multiplication is usually thought to be much slower than addition, so it makes sense to just count the multiplications (and divisions).

It is not hard to show that using Gaussian elimination on an $n\times n$ matrix to compute the determinant typically requires $(n^3+2n-3)/3$ multiplications.

The [Leibniz formula for determinants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_determinants) has $n!$ terms, each with $n-1$ multiplications, and therefore has $(n-1)n!$ multiplications.

The method of [Laplace cofactor expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofactor_expansion) is somewhat faster, since it collects terms together before mutliplying.  It only takes $n(2^{n-1}-1)$ multiplications.

Using these formulas, we can make a table showing the difficulty of each method:
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
n & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
\hline
\mathrm{Gauss} & 3 & 10 & 23 & 44 & 75 \\
\hline
\mathrm{Leibniz} & 2 & 12 & 72 & 480 & 3600\\
\hline
\mathrm{Laplace} & 2 & 9 & 28 & 75 & 186 \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$
As you can see, the Laplace expansion is best for $2\times 2$ and $3\times 3$, but Gaussian elimination becomes better starting with $4\times 4$ matrices.  (Though it's very close -- computing a $4\times 4$ determinant using cofactor expansion only takes 22% more time.)

Note that the formulas above are exact.  When you read that Gaussian elimination has running time "on the order of $n^3$", all this means is that the formula for the number of steps is *some* kind of cubic polynomial.  All cubic polynomials grow at roughly the same rate, up to multiplication by a constant, so saying that Gaussian elimination has running time on the order of $n^3$ tells you *approximately* how quickly the running time grows.  But it makes no sense to plug specific numbers into $n^3$, because $n^3$ is only an approximate formula -- specifically, it's an approximation for $(n^3+2n-3)/3$.